# Attribute Routing in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

i have table "Address" in Database in which address are saved by Post codes/Zip Codes

i want to retrive these address by postCode But Its is Not working

Post code formate =  Le2 2SN

here is my code

```
  [Route("{id:length(6)}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAddress(string id)
        {
            Address address = (db.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.postCode == id.ToUpper() )) ;

        }
```

Kindly help me .
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
[Route("api/YourControllerName/{id:length(6)}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetAddress(string id){ // }
```

Note: your Post code format looks like it has 7 characters which include a space character. If that's your correct format, you need to change the length to 7.